# Join Query to return a single row with Multiple table

Tags: mysql

The query is for search an user by city or area

user_table:

```
id user_name
1  user 1
2  user 2
3  user 3
```

second table is:

```
 user_id area_id
   1       1
   1       2
   1       3
   1       4
   3       1
   3       2
   3       3
   3       4
```

and the area table is:

```
id area_name
 1  Area 1
 2  Area 2
 3  Area 3
 4  Area 4
```

It returns the record but I want to join the search with one more table as:

```
id city_name
 1  Area 

select * 
  from user_table as ut 
         left join second_table as st on ut.id=st.user_id 
         left join area_table as at on st.area_id  = at.id 
 where like at.area_name=%Area%
```

Comment: where like %Area% but where what like area? where 'object' like %Area% you can't just use where like

Comment: at.area_name=%Area%  i am sorry , i was trying it for the past few hours , thats why get frustrated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heum, if I understand well, you would like to get all users with informations about city and area where city name or area name match search.

Maybe you could try :

**I suppose you pass two different values which MUST match (from search) :**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM user_table AS u 
  JOIN city_table AS c ON u.id = c.user_id AND c.city_name LIKE '%City%'
  JOIN area_table AS a ON c.area_id = a.id AND a.area_name LIKE '%Area%'
```

It should return one line per user.

Comment: thanks for your answer i found the query with your suggestion too

Comment: Ok ! Maybe you can add a "+1" to answers and comments which helped you and publish your solution for others who would encounter the same issue

Comment: new to this stuff , thats why , Thanks